# How do I uninstall expo-modules from my project?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I installed expo-modules from [this](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) link, but now I want to uninstall it. How do I uninstall this with npm?

Comment: `npm uninstall expo-modules `

Answer (score 0):

open terminal, navigate to folder which contains node_modules then
type "npm uninstall package-name" and hit enter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).